# How to listen in real time incoming events from server side in Swift/ios?

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, sockets

i'm trying to build a simple basic chat in `swift` (`iOS`). I'm using `websockets` (`Socket.io`) for client-server communication (server in `nodejs`).

I can easily send messages to the server and update the view instantly thanks to the `IBAction` but i can't receive them from this one (server) in real-time. I have to re-launch the `iOS` simulator every time i want to see new messages because The `UIViewController` need to reload to display new incoming messages sent from the outside.

It seems i need to create a function that `listen/observe` continuously all events coming for the server in real time.

I need your help to find out how i can handle this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: In essence you need to set up a background process to monitor communication with the server and and notify the view when the server hands you more data.  There are a lot of ways to do that in the system, NSOperations, dispatch and GCD, pthreads, etc.  Even if you had a concurrency model, you also need to think about how communication is handled with the server.  Basically your question is too broad to answer concisely.

Comment: In fact i need to send/receive data asynchronously between my client (swift) and the server (nodejs). I'm not sure about how i can set this up by using GCD or NSOperations. As i said i'm using only websockets for communication so i'm a bit lost concerning what means should i use to make all these stuffs matching.